# Как правильно передать массив с JS в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Имеется input,в который пользователь вводит номера. Можно ввести хоть 100 номеров

```
<form id="checkItemForm" onsubmit="return checkItemArr()" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input id="item_number" type="number" class="form-control" name="item_number" placeholder="Номер товара:" autofocus required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="check_item">Проверить</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Номера заполняются в массив JS

```
var items = [];

function checkItemArr() {
    value = document.getElementById("item_number").value;
    items.push(value);
    document.getElementById("checkItemForm").reset();
    document.getElementById("item_number").focus();
    return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../main/stock/test.php",
        data: { items : JSON.stringify(items) },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.reply);
        }
    });
}
```

Но проблема в том, что массив не передается в PHP для дальнейшей работы с БД итд. Просто пустая переменная, либо она не определена
Не понимаю, в чем причина. Может нужна какая-то другая реализация?

Comment: конечно не передается, ведь у вас `return false;` до передачи.

Comment: А как у вас можно ввести несколько номеров? Я вижу только один input

Comment: @NoSkill, Кстати, да. Надо будет проверить. Как-то не обратил внимание)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, в один инпут можно ввести сразу несколько номеров. При каждом подтверждении, отсылается на написанную функцию JS,где идет обработка и запись в массив

Comment: Эти несколько номером не отправятся в виде массива.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, все спокойно отправляется - проверил и сделал рабочий вариант. Ошибка была в return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле с JS нужно переместить return false; в конец функции, из-за этого и была причина неработоспособности кода
Спасибо первому комментатору выше!

Comment: вместо `return false` хорошей практикой является использование `event.preventDefault()`, это можно писать в любом месте.